# Scikit-learn ColumnTransformer + OneHotEncoder

Tags: scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
import numpy as np

X = [['male', 0, 3], ['male', 1, 0], ['female', 2, 1], ['female', 0, 2]]

# 字符串编码为整形
sex_enc = OrdinalEncoder(dtype = np.int)

# 独热编码
one_hot_enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore', dtype=np.int)

# 对第0列的字符串做整形转换, 然后对所有列做one-hot
col_transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('sex_enc', sex_enc, [0]), ('one_hot_enc', one_hot_enc, [0])])

# 训练编码
col_transformer.fit(X)
X_trans = col_transformer.transform(X)
print(X_trans)
```

> [[1 0 1]  [1 0 1]  [0 1 0]  [0 1 0]]

feature0 has values `male` and `female`, why one-hot outputs threes cols with columntransformer?

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Following the advices of the community, it is recommended to include context to your source code in order to receive the proper responses. Please check the documentation [on how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)